# How to find and replace text in CKEditor using Javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors, ckeditor

How could I find and replace text in CKEditor using Javascript?
Thanks for your suggestion!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

try this

```
editor = CKEDITOR.instances.fck; //fck is just my instance name you will need to replace that with yours

var edata = editor.getData();

var replaced_text = edata.replace("idontwant", "iwant this instead"); // you could also use a regex in the replace 

editor.setData(replaced_text);
```

you may want to put that in a blur event or soemthing

Comment: @StanislasPiotrowski Check out this link http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/api/CKEDITOR.editor-event-change

Comment: @mcgrailm i dont want to put it in blur event i want to replace content in condition

Comment: @mcgrailm, this is replacing only one instance. How can I replace all the instances.

Comment: @Abhijit . you'd have to create a loop somehow to get through them all so you'll have to figure out how you are going to target them. for example give each one a class then target the class and loop. Does that make sense.