# Wrap tables in div with CKEditor in Drupal textarea input

Tags: drupal-6, ckeditor, user-input

I'm working in Drupal, got CKEditor set up and have the tables plugin going on. The design I'm working with requires some visual elements that would be made A LOT easier if I had a div with a class wrapped around the tables in the output (because tables can't have padding on their sides in IE)...

SO.. I'm can think of 2 ways to do it, but don't know and can't figure out how to do either:

1)Use CKEditor to wrap all table elemnts in a div with a class..

2)Use Drupal input filter to wrap all table elements in a div with a class..

Does anyone know how to do either?

I don't want to add the div on page load.. that would cause a jump, and depend on javascript for the output.

This seems promising: [How to find and replace text in CKEditor using Javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5635118/how-to-find-and-replace-text-in-ckeditor-using-javascript) but is it reliable?  It seems kinda hackish and if a non-dev type is going be using the Editor it has to be 100% foolproof..

thanks!

Comment: Well, if anyone is still interested: for the #2 solution you can implement `hook_filter()`. And you can use regex to find and wrap the table in a `div`. Or load the XML from the string and use XML to manipulate the structure. I think the second approach is better and you can have regex as a last resort in case the XML could not be loaded or something.

Comment: Definitely look into hook_filter() -- the downside, however, is that you'll have to wait until the user submits the form before the wrap happens.  So the real solution involves a combination of both 1 and 2.  I had to do something similar and unfortunately the CKEditor API documentation is awful and it's hard to hook into.  I ended up making core edits which is evil evil evil... i'm sorry i don't have  a solution worth posting back here