# trouble with ckeditor and javascript

Tags: php, javascript, replace, ckeditor

I met some trouble with javascript and ckeditor.

I've done a function that will replace in a textarea all abreviations by their expression, for example tel -> telephone, etc....

The trouble is with ckeditor. on a normal textarea this function works fine, like that:

```
var abbreviations = {
    <?php $rqt="SELECT * FROM `glossaire` WHERE `id_company` ='".$societe['id']."'";
    $result=mysql_query($rqt);
    while($data=mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
    {?>
    "<?php echo ($data['libelle']) ; ?>": "<?php echo ($data['texte']) ; ?>",
     <?php } ?>    



};

function abbrReplace(el, abbrs) {
    if (!el || !abbrs) {
        return false;
    }
    else {
        var val = el.value,
            words = val.split(/\s/);
        for (var i = 0, len = words.length; i<len; i++) {
            if (abbrs[words[i]]) {
                words[i] = abbrs[words[i]];
            }
        }
        return words.join(' ');
    }
}

document.getElementById("suivi").onkeyup = function(){
    this.value = abbrReplace(this, abbreviations);
};
```

So on ckeditor, I've tried this : `CKEDITOR.instances.commentaire.insertText('abbreviations');`

Like that:

```
var abbreviations = {
    <?php $rqt="SELECT * FROM `glossaire` WHERE `id_company` ='".$societe['id']."'";
    $result=mysql_query($rqt);
    while($data=mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
    {?>
    "<?php echo ($data['libelle']) ; ?>": "<?php echo ($data['texte']) ; ?>",
     <?php } ?>    



};

function abbrReplace(el, abbrs) {
    if (!el || !abbrs) {
        return false;
    }
    else {
        var val = el.value,
            words = val.split(/\s/);
        for (var i = 0, len = words.length; i<len; i++) {
            if (abbrs[words[i]]) {
                words[i] = abbrs[words[i]];
            }
        }
        return words.join(' ');
    }
}

document.getElementById("suivi").onkeyup = function(){
    this.value = CKEDITOR.instances.commentaire.insertText('abbreviations');
};
```

I'm really lost, on ckeditor it does not work,

I think I do something wrong, butg I do not know how to correct it.

Anykind of help will be much appreciated.

Kind Regards.

SP.

Comment: I suppose you need something like this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5635118/how-to-find-and-replace-text-in-ckeditor-using-javascript

Comment: Dear Sir, thanks for you reply, I've tried this code but this one does not work onkeyup

Comment: Please, post your code in http://jsfiddle.net/, so we can better understand what is your problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/hooy/DU83p/ — here is working sample.

to bind `onKeyUp` function on CKEDITOR you cat use `ckeditor.on('key', someFunction);​`

Also, `setFocusToEnd` function is necessary because of [How to set cursor position to end of text in CKEditor?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4536532/ckeditor-set-cursor-position-to-end-of-text)