# Read only part in CKEditor

Tags: ckeditor

i'm using CKEditor to show some text 
i have a requirement to prevent editing in some Parts of the text
which will be inserted by JQuery

what i have done 
i inserted the input with class so i can change its value

```
 config.extraAllowedContent = 'input(*)';

<textarea name="editor1" id="editor1" rows="10" cols="80">
       Some Text <input type="text" id="txttest" class="form-control" style="border:none" />        
    </textarea> 

<script>  
var ed1;
ed1 = CKEDITOR.replace('editor1');ed1.on('loaded', function () {            
            $('.form-control')[0].val('Doctor'); });
</script>
```

the Problem here i can't find the input $('.form-control') allows return 0 lenght

the second try

```
var ed1;


$(document).ready(function () {

    var data = ' Some Text < input type = "text" id = "txttest" class="form-control" style = "border:none" value = "Doctor" />';
    ed1 = CKEDITOR.replace('editor1');

    CKEDITOR.instances['editor1'].setData(data)
```

the problem here the CKEditor render the input as plain text not html

any Help Please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank You All
this is the answer for my question for anyone will face the same problem
Thanks to that Post 

    [How to find and replace text in CKEditor using Javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5635118/how-to-find-and-replace-text-in-ckeditor-using-javascript)

the Code

```
<textarea name="editor1" id="editor1" rows="10" cols="80">
        Some Text.
<input type="text" id="txttest" class="form-control" style="border:none" value="yyy" />
            </textarea>
<script>  
var ed1;
ed1 = CKEDITOR.replace('editor1');

$(document).ready(function () {


    var editor = CKEDITOR.instances['editor1'];
    var edata = editor.getData();

    var replaced_text = edata.replace("yyy", "iwant this instead"); // you could also use a regex in the replace 

    editor.setData(replaced_text);

});
```